# When does getSimSerialNumber return a null value?

Tags: android, sim-card

So here's the scenario.

When I had first tested my application which uses
getSimSerialNumber() function, I successfully got my SIM Number to be "89912000107679766XYZ".

Now, everytime I run the same function, irrespective of Airplane Mode being on or off, I keep getting Null Value.

I tried to check using getSimState(), and I always get the Constant value 5, which is "SIM_STATE_READY".

Where exactly is the issue? Why wouldn't I get the correct SimSerialNumber now?

**EDIT 1:**

Code base for reference:

```
public void doSimStateCheck(Context c){
        String savedSimCardNo = ClientConfig.readSimCardNumber(c); // I have saved device's sim card somewhere here.
        String existingSimCardNo = ""; 
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String simID = "";
        boolean airPlaneMode = isAirplaneModeOn(c);
        if(airPlaneMode){
            // toggle airplane mode
            setAirplaneModeOn(c,0); //Setting Airplane mode on - this might not work as stated for Jellybean and above. I have given WRITE_SETTINGS and WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS permission already. I am not worried about this piece of code anyways.
            simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber();
            setAirplaneModeOn(c, 1); //Setting Airplane mode back to off.
        }
        else{
            simID = tm.getSimSerialNumber(); // I am getting null here, i.e. when Airplane mode is NOT on, still I get null :( THIS IS MY CONCERN.
        }

        if (simID != null)
            existingSimCardNo = simID;
        else{
            Log.v("SimState",""+tm.getSimState()); // This always returns 5.
            existingSimCardNo = "NULL";
        }

        Log.v("SavedSimCardState", "It is " + savedSimCardNo); //This returns 89912000107679766XYZ
        Log.v("ExistingSimCardState","It is "+existingSimCardNo); //This shows NULL as stated above.
        if(!savedSimCardNo.equals(existingSimCardNo)){
           //do stuff when sim card numbers are not same as saved earlier.
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        } else {
            return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 0;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    public static void setAirplaneModeOn(Context context,int state) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state);
        } else {
            Settings.Global.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, state);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, of course I would have, otherwise how would I first the get the correct Sim Number "89912000107679766XYZ" in my first run? ;)

Comment: what has changed between your "first test" and "now"?

Comment: Nothing has changed around the piece of code that reads Sim card number. I did add a check for Airplane mode ON/OFF though.

Comment: Can you post the code here?

Comment: Sure, added the same! :)

Comment: Would it have anything to do with network activation of SIM Card? If the SIM Card is not activated over network (something like a dummy unused SIM), would it give NULL value?